# using python markdown .convert() in django views

Tags: python, django, markdown

I have a blog that uses markdown. I am trying to convert it to HTML in `views.py` with [python markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown). For individual posts, this code works:

```
def detail_view(request, slug):
    md = markdown.Markdown()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    postcontent = md.convert(post.md_text)
    context = {...}
    return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

However, applying the same logic to a view meant to show multiple posts fails:

```
def home_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-id')
    md = markdown.Markdown()
    for markdown in posts:
        postcontent = md.convert(posts.md_text)
    context = {...}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

What would I need to change to convert the `text_md` field(s) of my Post model in this view? Is `.convert()` the right method?
Thanks in advance!